# lists, sublists in html

Tags: html, html-lists

How to organize html code (with usage ol\li, ul\li ect.) to present such lists (with sublists)?

```
1. Section
    1.1. subsection
    1.2. subsection
    1.3. subsection
2. Section
3. Section
    3.1. subsection
           • text
           • text
           • text
    3.2. subsection
    3.3. subsection


ol { 
    counter-reset: section;
    list-style-type: none;
}

li:before {
    content: counters(section, ".") ". "; 
    counter-increment: section;
}

<ol>
  <li>Section
    <ol>
      <li>subsection</li>
      <li>subsection</li>
      <li>subsection</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>Section</li>
  <li>Section
    <ol>
      <li>subsection</li>
      <ul>
       <li>text</li>
       <li>text</li>
       <li>text</li>
      </ul>
      <li>subsection</li>
      <li>subsection</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
</ol>
```

note: It is not the same that I want [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UGsee.jpg)

So far, using  has produced only 1, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 2., 3., 3.1., 3.2., 3.3, 3.4., 3.5., 3.6.

not 1, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 2., 3., 3.1., •, •, •, 3.2., 3.3,

I think thats all, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is your `li:before` also applies to the elements in the unordered list. Try this out and let me know if it works:

```css
ol {
  counter-reset: section;
  list-style-type: none;
}

li:before {
  content: counters(section, ".") ". ";
  counter-increment: section;
  color: #BA4917;
}

ul li:before {
  content: "";
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>Section
    <ol>
      <li>subsection</li>
      <li>subsection</li>
      <li>subsection</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>Section</li>
  <li>Section
    <ol>
      <li>subsection
        <ul>
          <li>text</li>
          <li>text</li>
          <li>text</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>subsection</li>
      <li>subsection</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: You edited the post. The earlier solution was good. Please restore the original post.

Comment: Sure thing there you go. You prefer the overriding of `ul li` to only selecting `ol li` elements?

Comment: In fact I just noticed, this solution has incorrect numbering whereas the newer solution didn't, why did you prefer this one?